# Backslash can not be inserted in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 on Windows with German keyboard. The backslash `\` is assigned to `alt gr + ß` but this key binding is not properly working. (The cursor goes up by several lines.)

Since `alt gr` is equivalent to `ctrl+alt` on Windows, I added the following line in sublime-keymap.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+ß"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\\"} }
```

But this is not working, neither.

Is it possible to assign `\` to `alt gr+ß`?

Note:

- `"keys": ["ctrl+alt+0"]` (instead of `"keys": ["ctrl+alt+ß"]`) works. But I want use "alt gr+ß" for backslash.
- `"keys": ["ctrl+alt+\u00DF"]` is not working.

Comment: Use sublime.log_input(True) in the console and press "ctrl+alt+ß" to see what Sublime Text understands.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! That is "ctrl+alt+["

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following settings works perfect!

In `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings`

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+["], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\\"} }
```

Comment: I had the same problem additionally with "]" and "}" on the German keyboard on windows 10. Thanks also to the comment above about the console and using sublime.log_input(True), the keys for these two are "ctrl+alt+9" for "]" and and "ctrl+alt+0" for "}" in my case.